# Power BI giving wrong answer when subtracting a constant

Tags: powerbi

I am experiencing an interesting/unexpected result when trying to subtract a constant number from a column. As you can see in the screenshot, the "hours_working_days" is correctly calculating 2080 working hours in a year, but when I try to subtract the value 114 from the field I get -39530. Any ideas what could be causing this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This looks like a computed column. This means that in *every row*, you now have a value that''s -114 less than what's in `hours_working_days`. If you then aggregate these values, you get a value that's -114 * number of rows less than the `hours_working_days` total (which tells me you have 365 rows in your tablem which fits neatly with the year). Presumably you intended to create a *measure*, subtracting 114 from the *total* number of `hours_working_days`.

Comment: Note that subtracting a constant will not necessarily work correctly if a selection of data is made that's not exactly one year, so perhaps you want something like `COUNT(hours_working_days) / 365 * 114` instead, to calculate the value proportional to the year.